# Skip particular method from showing up in stacktrace

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, stack-trace

I have been trying to get a reliable way of printing the stack trace at runtime on mobile devices. I came across `System.Environment.StackTrace`

I am trying something with 3 classes right now:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {
    public static void Do() {
        Test3.ActionThing(() => {
            Test2.DoSomethingElse();
        });
    }
}


public class Test2 : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
        Test3.ActionThing(() => {
            Debug.Log("Start execution");
            Test.Do();
        });
    }

    public static void DoSomethingElse(){
        Test3.ActionThing(() => {
            var a = 0;
            a = int.Parse("s1");
        });
    }
}

public class Test3 : MonoBehaviour {
    public static void ActionThing(Action act){
        try{
            if (act != null)
                act();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Debug.LogError("Error occured " + e.Message);
            Debug.LogError("StackTrace was " + Environment.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

I get this stacktrace when the error is thrown

```
StackTrace was    at System.Environment.get_StackTrace() in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Environment.cs:line 227
   at Test3.ActionThing(System.Action act) in <ProjectPath>\Test3.cs:line 13
   at Test2.DoSomethingElse() in <ProjectPath>\Test2.cs:line 14
   at Test.<Do>m__0() in <ProjectPath>\Test.cs:line 8
   at Test3.ActionThing(System.Action act) in <ProjectPath>\Test3.cs:line 10
   at Test.Do() in <ProjectPath>\Test.cs:line 7
   at Test2.<Start>m__0() in <ProjectPath>\Test2.cs:line 9
   at Test3.ActionThing(System.Action act) in <ProjectPath>\Test3.cs:line 10
   at Test2.Start() in <ProjectPath>\Test2.cs:line 7
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Test3:ActionThing(Action) (at Assets/Test3.cs:13)
Test2:DoSomethingElse() (at Assets/Test2.cs:14)
Test:<Do>m__0() (at Assets/Test.cs:8)
Test3:ActionThing(Action) (at Assets/Test3.cs:10)
Test:Do() (at Assets/Test.cs:7)
Test2:<Start>m__0() (at Assets/Test2.cs:9)
Test3:ActionThing(Action) (at Assets/Test3.cs:10)
Test2:Start() (at Assets/Test2.cs:7)
```

Obviously, since I want this to be a Debug in the release build, it wont show the internal stack trace, and only the message.

But the problem lies in the stacktrace itself, where it even prints the method `at Test3.ActionThing(System.Action act) in <ProjectPath>\Test3.cs:line 10`. I want to skip this from showing up in the stack trace.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance. If the question seems too long, please suggest edits :)

Comment: Why don't you want the `Test3.ActionThing(System.Action act)` line in the stack trace?  It would be a simple matter to process the `Environment.StackTrace` and remove unwanted lines but its not clear what makes some lines acceptable and others not

Comment: The general idea for that method was to route all code through it, so that if it throws errors, I could see/print them in 1 place. But if a chain of methods getting called is too long, and everything is routed through said method, this string would be rather long, and it'd make the error less easy to understand quickly, along with unnecessary stack entries

Comment: I presume you wouldn't want `System.Environment.get_StackTrace()` either ?

Comment: That would be awesome too, but I don't mind that since that'll be a one time print in the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward approach is to simply process the `Environment.StackTrace` string and whipe out the stack frames you don't care about.

```
 public static void ActionThing(Action act){
    try{
        if (act != null)
            act();
    }catch(Exception e){
        var relevantStackFrames = 
            Environment.StackTrace
                .Split('\n')
                .Skip(2)
                .ToArray();
        var relevantStackTrace = string.Join("\n", relevantStackFrames);
        Debug.LogError("Error occured " + e.Message);
        Debug.LogError("StackTrace was " + relevantStackTrace );
    }
}
```

The line where we assign to `relevantStackFrames` splits the stack trace string into an array of strings, with each element being the line for a corresponding stack frame.  The stack frames for `System.Environment.get_StackTrace()` and `Test3.ActionThing(System.Action act)` are the first two elements in this array, and since you don't want them, we use linq's `Skip` function to exclude them from the collection.  Then we convert the result of the skip operation into an array with `ToArray`.  So `relevantStackFrames` is an array of stack frame strings excluding the ones you don't want.

Then we make a string called `relevantStackTrace` which will contain the string for the whole stack trace.   We just join each element of `relevantStackTrace` and put the line breaks back with `string.Join`.

Remember to add `using System.Linq` so you get access to `Skip` and `ToArray`

Comment: I've used toarray and string.Join before. I'm yet to have used Skip, so I'm not sure how it works. But guessing by the method name, it'll skip the second element from the stack trace's split array. Which is a hard coded value, which may not work all the time, if the method chain is different.

Comment: I had considered string manipulation myself, but I'm not a huge fan of that usually. I'll accept this answer if this works and there's no better solution. Thanks again

Comment: I think the hard coded value isn't a problem in this case because you always know exactly how many frames you want to skip (the error handling function and the call stack getter).  But you could do more complicated stuff if you really need, like filtering out stack frames that contain the functions you know you are not interested in.

Comment: Also an important point: `Skip` **doesn't skip the second element, it skips two elements.**  If you want to skip the second element you could replace `Skip(2)` with `Take(1).Skip(1)`

Comment: I'm accepting the answer, since it seemed to have worked to some extent. It removed the first occurrence of the ActionThing method, but not the second one. But I'll figure it out

Comment: You should use the StackTrace class instead if it's available. See me answer.

Answer (score 0):

If available, you can use the `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` class with the `skipFrames` parameter to get the current stack with any number of frames omitted.

```
 public static void ActionThing(Action act){
    try{
        if (act != null)
            act();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Debug.LogError("Error occured " + e.Message);
        // new StackTrace(1) captures the current stack and skips 1 frame.
        Debug.LogError("StackTrace was " + new StackTrace(1) );
    }
}
```